# Convert a list of objects to an xml string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xelement

Hello I have a list of object i want to convert into an xml. Here is what the final xml should look like.

```
<ArrayOfTweet>
    <Tweet>
        <Photos>
            <Photo>
                <PhotoHeight>FOO</PhotoHeight>
                <PhotoUri>a/random/ur/path</PhotoUri>
                <PhotoWidth>923</PhotoWidth>
                <SourcePhotoUri>a/random/path</SourcePhotoUri>
            </Photo>
        </Photos>
        <ProfileImage>a/random/path</ProfileImage>
        <ScreenName>FOO</ScreenName>
        <Text>some text</Text>
        <TweetId>1234</TweetId>
        <UserId>1234</UserId>
        <Username>BAR</Username>
    </Tweet>
    <Tweet>
        <Photos>
            <Photo>
                <PhotoHeight>FOO</PhotoHeight>
                <PhotoUri>a/random/ur/path</PhotoUri>
                <PhotoWidth>923</PhotoWidth>
                <SourcePhotoUri>a/random/path</SourcePhotoUri>
            </Photo>
        </Photos>
        <ProfileImage>a/random/path</ProfileImage>
        <ScreenName>FOO</ScreenName>
        <Text>some text</Text>
        <TweetId>1234</TweetId>
        <UserId>1234</UserId>
        <Username>BAR</Username>
    </Tweet>
</ArrayOfTweet>
```

I have converted each of the objects in the list into an xml string like so

```
//TweetList is the list of tweet objects

List<string> xmlStringTweetList = new List<string>();
foreach (var tl in TweetList)
{
    xmlStringTweetList.Add(toXML(tl));
}

private string toXML(Tweet t)
{
    var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, t);
    return stringwriter.ToString();
}
```

I tried converting that list into the format above using

```
XElement xmlElements = new XElement("ArrayOfTweet", xmlStringTweetList.Select(i => new XElement("Tweet", i)));
```

But there is the extra `<Tweet></Tweet>`  That i dont need. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Why aren't you taking an entire object structure and serializing all at once?

Comment: You mean serialize the TweetList object? I tried that but i could not figure out how to make that work properly. I getting errors. Do you have a suggestion of a way to do that? I would be happy to do it that way, since it would be easier

Comment: I just posted an answer with how to serialize it as one object.

Comment: The types in square bracket are wrong.  Take out the [XmlArray] above Tweet and replace with [XmlElement].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ye0Nrf) that illustrates a way to serialize your object all at once, instead of piecing strings together.

I suspect your extra `<Tweet></Tweet>` is because of a null or empty value in the list, because I am not experiencing it in my test above.

Answer (score 1):

I think `XElement xmlElements = new XElement("ArrayOfTweet", xmlStringTweetList.Select(i => XElement.Parse(i)));` should do.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I get an error System.Xml.XmlElement does not contain a definition for 'Parse' but i check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714(v=vs.110).aspx and it is there. ill have to figure out why this is

Comment: Sorry, it should be  `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: Thanks Martin i made the changes and it worked too! But i will go with @maccetturas fiddle because it is clean.